# Por que não funciona o atributo required?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho estes dois códigos abaixo, em que o JavaScript não deixa ativar o atributo `required` e já experimentei muitas formas, mas não fazem efeito. Alguém tem uma solução para isso?

```js
/**
 * Captuar o elemento responsável por 
 * capturar o valor digitado pelo usuário
 */
const inputSearch = document.querySelector('input[name="q"]')

/**
 * Aplica um evento, do tipo "click", nos botões de pesquisa.
 * Para evitar incompatibilidades, você pode substituir o `forEach`
 * por um `for` "simples"
 */
document.querySelectorAll("#google-search, #wikipedia-search, #yahoo-search, #bing-search, #yandex-search, #duckduckgo, #archive-search, #ask-search, #aol-search, #Baidu-search, #infopedia-search, #wolframalpha-search, #cambio-search, #tempo-search, #dicionariopenal-search, #interpretacaocpp-search, #interpretacaocp-search")
  .forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', search))

/**
 * Função responsável por identificar o botão pressionado,
 * e enviar o usuário para o site correto.
 *
 * @param {EventTarget} event
 * @return void
 */
function search(event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  const anchor = document.createElement('a')
  anchor.target = "_self"
  anchor.href = `${event.target.getAttribute('formaction')}${encodeURI(inputSearch.value)}`
  anchor.click()
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="col-sm-7" style="width:52%;height:44px;border: 1px solid #ebebeb;position: relative;top: 3px;background-color:#ffffff;" id="searchresultsquery" placeholder="Escreva o número do artigo do CPP e faça enter..." autofocus name="q" size="70" maxlength="70" required/>

<input type="image" id="dicionariopenal-search" style="width:45px;position: relative;left:0px;top:19px;" src="https://www.clubesorte.pt/corampopulo/c_elements/images/fotos/search-image1.png" alt="Submit Form" formaction="https://www.clubesorte.pt/corampopulo/login/interpretacao-cpp/palavras.php?letter=artigo ">
</form>
```

Comment: `required` só funciona com form submit.

Comment: Meireles, além da informação do Augusto, você utilizou o required de forma incorreto, na verdade, basta declarar o atributo (é como se fosse um boolean), veja um exemplo aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Answer (score 3):

Como dito pelo [Augusto Vasques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques) em [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/414567/porque-n%c3%a3o-funciona-o-atributo-required#comment808080_414567), o atributo `required` só realiza a verificação na submissão do formulário. Vale ressaltar que após essa validação, o evento [`submit` de um formulário](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) é disparado se estiver tudo *válido*.

Exemplo desse comportamento:

```html
<form>
  <input required />
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Portanto, entre as milhares de coisas que você pode fazer para resolver esse *problema*, citarei duas:

#### Trocar o evento `click` do botão para o `submit` do formulário:

Essa me parece a opção mais semanticamente correta, já que o que você está tratando, no final, é a submissão desse pequeno formulário. Ademais, dessa forma, você pode usar a validação nativa dos navegadores, já que o evento `submit` é disparado se o formulário estiver "válido". :)

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const nameField = form.querySelector('input');

form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
  const value = nameField.value;
  
  console.log(`Submetido: "${value}".`);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input required />
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

#### Fazer a validação do input dentro do *handler* do evento `click` do botão:

Diferentemente da opção anterior, essa não me parece tão adequada aos olhos da semântica, já que o `click` não é tão correto quanto um `submit`. Mas ainda assim, é uma alternativa.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const nameField = document.querySelector('input');

button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  // Previne a submissão do formulário:
  event.preventDefault();

  const { value } = nameField;
  
  if (!value) {
    console.log('Complete os campos!');
    return;
  }
  
  console.log(`Submetido: "${value}".`);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input required />
  <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Agradeço toda a vossa ajuda mas na verdade experimentei tudo e não funciona porque o js de origem anula todas as possibilidades, mas ele é necessário para o funcionamento da pesquisa que vem da base de dados. Talvez exista uma solução se for alterado o js de origem?

Comment: Como assim, "anula"? Poderia detalhar esses fatores um pouco mais na sua pergunta?

Comment: Quer dizer que se eu apagar aquele js o atributo required já funciona, portanto... é ele que está a determinar um qualquer factor diverso que anula todas as soluções pois basta apagá-lo e tudo funciona excepto a pesquisa que é o mais importante.